# Jquery click function only gets called once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JavaScript to implement a functionality. I have an icon on my html page (div tag). and I want to implement the functionality that when I click on it once it changes to another icon. But the condition it when i click on that changed icon, it should revert back to the original icon.

Now, here is the problem, the icon changes to another icon on first click but it does not revert back to original icon on second click. Actually, its jquery's click function is not getting called when i click it second time.

any ideas?

Following is the code:

```
$("#volume-slide-img").hide();

$("#volume-icon").click(function() {
    if (document.getElementById('volume-slide-img').style.display == 'none') {
        $("#volume-slide-img").show();
    }
    else {
        $("#volume-slide-img").hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: That code works for me. Problem might lie somewhere else. Do you have the full code? And plz format it better, maybe use jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make your code a lot simpler. Try this:

```
$('#volume-slide-img').hide();
$('#volume-icon').click(function(){
    $('#volume-slide-img').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is toggle the class on #volume-icon when it is clicked.

[I mocked it up on jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Na2Eg/) When the icon is clicked, `toggleClass` will do what it says, toggle a class (if it is applied, unapply it, if not, apply it). The class can be used to set the icon.

I might be missing something though...you say "I have an icon" and you want to do something "when I click on it" but your code sample seems to change something *else* when the icon is clicked.

Comment: no its just an icon which on clicking shows that icon + new icon (which is hidden by default). Does that make any sense?

Comment: I think so. In that case your original should work. Where are your scripts located on the page?

Answer (score 0):

@Don Zacharias nailed it, but I found some pretty volume icons so here's a similar approach to his but with background images.

http://jsfiddle.net/pxfunc/xbUQZ/

HTML:

```
<div id="volume-icon" title="click to toggle!"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#volume-icon {
    width:256px;
    height:256px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-image:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/icons-land/vista-multimedia/256/Volume-Hot-icon.png')
}
#volume-icon.mute {
    background-image:url('http://lh3.ggpht.com/_uU5cLRayUdQ/S48MYDVnjlI/AAAAAAAADik/GWYRNg06mhE/Volume-Normal-Red-icon.png');
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#volume-icon').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('mute');
});
```